# How do I change the pin mode on the BeagleBone Green?

Tags: gpio, beagleboard

I'm looking to set the mode to 7 for a lot of the pins since I need more GPIOs.  I've tried downloading different python scripts from github to help with it, and I've also looked into using bonescript, but that's not working on my board.  Any ideas are welcome.

Edit: the other question mentioned in the comments doesn't work for me.  I tried the solution and I get to the point where you need to modify slots.  Then, when I try to do that, it says operation `no such file or directory`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Pins Mode Beaglebone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872763/configuring-pins-mode-beaglebone)

Comment: I've tried that and I can't get that to work

Comment: how does it not work?

Comment: When I try to modify the slots file in the /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/, it says `write error: No such file or directory`